# How to identify the server providing a DNS response?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, nslookup, dns-lookup

**TL;DR:** Where, in a `nslookup www.somedomain.com -debug` will I find the name/IP of the server(s) which reply to the chain of queries?

**Details:**

I have a setup (Windows 10 machine)

- which is connected to a corporate LAN (`example.corp`) and has an outbound OpenVPN connection in place (to `example.customer`)
- where the DNS requests are delegated to a local (`127.0.0.1`) server (namely [Unbound](https://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/about/))

This DNS server is set up to forward DNS queries:

- `example.corp` to a corporate DNS
- `example.customer` to a customer DNS behind the VPN
- Internet hosts (`google.com`, ...) to the the customer DNS behind the VPN (there are several reasons for that, instead of using the corporate DNS or providers such as `1.1.1.1`)

I now would like to make sure that the right server resolves the right queries. This is easy for the corporate and customer related ones (nobody else can resolve them correctly, so if they are resolved it means the right DNS was hit) but I had doubts about the Internet ones (which could ultimately be correctly resolved by either of them).

The solution I used was to monitor the traffic of the VPN and see whether there would relevant DNS packets going through. There were so I know that teh setup is OK.

**This approach is not the best one, I would prefer to use the capabilities of `nslookup` to find out that.** I tried to `set debug` in the tool and see what would come out for an query of an internet machine (`yahoo.fr`).

The resolving first went though `yahoo.fr.somesubdomain.example.corp`, `yahoo.fr.someothersubdomain.example.corp` - everything which is in the list of domain suffixes. Obviously none of the queries went through and the next one was tried. An example:

```
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 99, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        yahoo.fr.somesubdomain.example.corp, type = AAAA, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  (root)
        ttl = 3440 (57 mins 20 secs)
        primary name server = thecorpnsserver.example.corp
        responsible mail addr = root.thecorpnsserver.example.corp
        serial  = 2018113000
        refresh = 1800 (30 mins)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 86400 (1 day)
```

This is a failed query, but there I do not see anywhere the server which responded (this is not `thecorpnsserver.example.corp` which is just part of the `SOA` of `example.corp`). In other words, the one which provided the `SOA` (`AUTHORITY RECORDS`)

I finally get my answer with

```
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 100, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 5,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        yahoo.fr, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  yahoo.fr
        internet address = 106.10.248.151
        ttl = 17 (17 secs)
    ->  yahoo.fr
        internet address = 98.136.103.24
        ttl = 17 (17 secs)
    ->  yahoo.fr
        internet address = 124.108.115.101
        ttl = 17 (17 secs)
    ->  yahoo.fr
        internet address = 74.6.136.151
        ttl = 17 (17 secs)
    ->  yahoo.fr
        internet address = 212.82.100.151
        ttl = 17 (17 secs)

------------
Non-authoritative answer:
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 101, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        yahoo.fr, type = AAAA, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  yahoo.fr
        ttl = 595 (9 mins 55 secs)
        primary name server = hidden-master.yahoo.com
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.yahoo-inc.com
        serial  = 2018112700
        refresh = 3600 (1 hour)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 600 (10 mins)

------------
Name:    yahoo.fr
Addresses:  106.10.248.151
          98.136.103.24
          124.108.115.101
          74.6.136.151
          212.82.100.151
```

but it still does not say which DNS server processed the request.

Answer (score 3):

When you launch nslookup in interactive mode the server being used is listed as "Default Server". That is the server that is being used by nslookup.

If you're looking for the upstream servers that the Default Server is using, you won't see that in nslookup.

Comment: Yes, in my case it has to be `127.0.0.1` as it is the only one set up. It is a pity, though, that there is no way to list the upstream servers being used (makes my debugging more difficult, though what I saw via wireshark is sufficient - I was just hoping for something baked into the query tool (`nslookup`))